# How can I get stripped image name using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, path, strip

Let's say I have an img element with src="img/highlow.png".

How can strip down to get `alert('highlow');`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to find the image, use `prop` (or `attr` if you have jQuery 1.5 or below) to get the `src` property, then  regex to get the part you want.

Your code might look like this:

```
alert($('#yourImageId').prop('src').match(/(\w*)\.\w{3,4}$/)[1]);
```

This assumes that the image has no non-word characters (i.e. it's only `A-Za-z0-9_`) and that its file extension is 3 or 4 characters long. If this isn't correct, you'll have to modify it.

Answer (score 5):

```
var src = $('#id_of_your_img_element').prop('src');
var name = src.replace(/^.*\/|\.png$/g, '');
alert(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

ex:

```
var x = "img/highlow.png";
var y = x.substring( x.lastIndexOf("/"), x.lastIndexOf(".") - 1);
```

Comment: There is not a single line of jQuery in your solution